# Check url-redirection using axios in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using axios for API calling in nodejs. 
I want to check if "https://origin.com/?url=https://destination.com" this url is redirecting to "destination.com". 
So which status/headers I can check in axios response.
What will be the condition to check if it goes to "destination.com"

```
var express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
var app = express();

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {

// Check if it redirects 
axios.get('https://origin.com/?url=https://destination.com')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);

    // Here I want to check if it redirects successfully to "destination.com"
    if (condition) {
        // Successfully redirected to "destination.com"
    }   

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

})


var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use https for api, then in the response header you can find that it direct to the "destination.com".

Https is much simple and easy to use.

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://encrypted.google.com/', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the redirect url under responseURL key, 
get fetchedUrl by

> const fetchedUrl = response.request.res.responseURL;

[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Ch5.png)

> Environment node: v8.9.4 axios: ^0.18.0